# reusing the backgroundworker more than once

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

i am using the background worker to do an expensive operation:

```
backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(inputs);
```

At the end i have this:

```
 void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   Messagebox.Show("Done with expensive operation 1"};
}
```

I now have another expensive operation.  Can i reuse this same background worker.  I now want new callbacks as i dont want switch statements on the ProgressChanged and DoWork Callbacks to determine if i am doing operation 1 or 2.

Is it just simpler to use 2 seperate background worker classes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can re-use a `BackgroundWorker` - but you can only use it once at any time - not concurrently. If the operations are different, however, I'd use a separate worker. Otherwise you'll have to unhook the events, hook the correct events, etc. Messy.