# Is The reuse of the backgroundworker object possible?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a button "refresh" which every time i click on it i want my backgroundworker object to work.

i use

```
if (main_news_back_worker.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // Start the asynchronous operation.

            main_news_back_worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
private void main_news_back_worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        show_system_urls(urls);
        displayNewMes(newMes, newStock, newSource);
        displayOldMes(oldMes, oldStock);

    }
```

The first time i use the backgroundworker it work good and also get to the RunWorkerCompleted and do his work. 
But the second time i try to run the object the is_busy property of the object is 'true' and i cant run the object again...

Do i need to create a new backgroundworker every time i want to run it? how do i do it?
Thanks.

Comment: "Yes, but not concurrently" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681076/reusing-the-backgroundworker-more-than-once

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, no problem.  You will however have to make sure that the user cannot click the button again while the BGW is busy.  Easily done by setting the Enabled property, stops the button action and provides excellent visual feedback to the user.  Try this for example:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: How do i create a new backgroundworker everytime i want to run the method? and how do i dispose of the previous one so that memory wont be lost. thanks.

Comment: The point of my answer was that you *don't* have to create a new BGW every time.  You can but I wouldn't recommend it, it is quite untrivial to close the form cleanly when you've got multiple bgws running.  Ask Henk.

Answer (score 1):

> But the second time i try to run the object the is_busy property of the object is 'true'

That means the first background action is still running.

You will first have to decide if you want 2 of these actions to be going on at the same time.

If No, implement Cancellation so that you can Stop (and then restart) the Bgw.

If Yes, create a new Bgw each time.

And while you can re-use a Bgw, and that makes sense in the 1st scenario, there is no great saving in doing so. The Bgw Thread comes from the ThreadPool and will be re-used anyway.

Comment: "implement Cancellation so that you can Stop (and then restart) the Bgw" how do i perform Cancellation? using main_news_back_worker.CancelAsync() dont work...

Comment: @Michael, your code in DoWork must co-operate. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx