# C# Confused As How To End BackgroundWorker After Work Is Completed

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am creating a program in which a section of it needs to connect to a work sql server, retrieves a list of active customer accounts, and then displays that list into a combobox. The code does what it is supposed to do during the initial loading of the form, but as soon as I attempt to run the backgroundworker from a refresh button, I get an error message:

> This BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently

I am confused as to why as in my mind, the code has obviously reached the end of the RunWorkerCompleted method.

```
private void EnterCompletions_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblcomboBox1Status.Text = "Attempting to download list of active accounts ...";

        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();          
    }

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // *** tblaccts - AID | AName ***
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT AID, AName " +
                                              "FROM tblaccts " +
                                              "WHERE Status IS NULL " +
                                              "ORDER BY AID ASC", myConnection);
        SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            accts_aid.Add(myReader["AID"].ToString());
            accts_aname.Add(myReader["AName"].ToString());
        }

        myConnection.Close();

        for (int i = 0; i < accts_aid.Count; i++) // create a list which contains strings in this format:  "account number | account name"
        {
            accts_string_aid.Add(accts_aid[i] + "  |  " + accts_aname[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < accts_aname.Count; i++) // create a list which contains strings in this format:  "account name | account number"
        {
            accts_string_name.Add(accts_aname[i] + "  |  " + accts_aid[i]);
        }

        accts_aid.Clear();
        accts_aname.Clear();
    }

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {           
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            if(rbAid.Checked)
            {
                foreach (string stuff in accts_string_aid) // fill the combobox with the custom display format:  "account number | account name"
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(stuff);
                }
                aid_or_name = "aid";
            }

            if(rbName.Checked)
            {
                foreach (string stuff in accts_string_name) // fill the combobox with the custom display format:  "account name | account number"
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(stuff);
                }
                aid_or_name = "name";
            }

            lblcomboBox1Status.Text = "Account list successfully downloaded.";
            comboBox1.Focus();
            comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;               
        }
        else
        {
            lblcomboBox1Status.Text = "Unable to connect to the server.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364304/is-the-reuse-of-the-backgroundworker-object-possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is The reuse of the backgroundworker object possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364304/is-the-reuse-of-the-backgroundworker-object-possible)